# How to get a value while discarding the unneeded parts?

Tags: bash

I've been browsing and searching for quite a while now and I've tried several approaches
but I seem to be doing something wrong.

I'm reading from /sys/bus/devices/w1/..., where the output looks like this:

```
46 01 4b 46 7f ff 0a 10 85 : crc=85 YES
46 01 4b 46 7f ff 0a 10 85 t=20375
```

I'm only interested in the "20375" (which equals 20.375°C if anyone cares)

I've used:

```
cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00000465f413/w1_slave | tr "t=" "\n"
```

...to get that value but I cannot get it into a separate Variable...

```
T1FILE=$(cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00000465f413/w1_slave | tr "t=" "\n")
T2FILE=$(cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000046612e5/w1_slave | tr "t=" "\n")
```

How can I do this?

Thanks for the help! Im using the awk variant!

```
T1=$(awk -F'=' '/ t=/ {print $NF }' /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00000465f413/w1_slave)
T2=$(awk -F'=' '/ t=/ {print $NF }' /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000046612e5/w1_slave)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), specifying `=` as the Field separator (`-F`), for every line containing the string "`t=`", `print` the last field (`$NF`) on that line, using `/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00000465f413/w1_slave` as input:

```
awk -F'=' '/ t=/ { print $NF }' /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00000465f413/w1_slave
```

Putting it all together:

```
T1FILE=$(awk -F'=' '/ t=/ { print $NF }' /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00000465f413/w1_slave)
```

Answer (score 1):

try grep:

```
grep -Po "(?<=t=)\d+" file
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "46 01 4b 46 7f ff 0a 10 85 : crc=85 YES
46 01 4b 46 7f ff 0a 10 85 t=20375"|grep -Po "(?<=t=)\d+"
20375
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk, doesn't require `t=` at the end of your line.

```
awk '{FS="t="} /t=/ { split($2, t," "); print t[1] }' /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00000465f413/w1_slave
```